# PHP - Session undefined on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

My login page: example.com/login *(root/public_html/login)*
My subdomain: api.example.com *(root/api)*

When I make a simple GET request using AngularJS $.http it fails to load the session variable. Directly loading the page works fine, but when using Angular it fails (Giving a CORS Error even though its on the same server and host just a different subdomain).

Is it possible making a js request to the absolute path (not relative path) causes a cors exception?

In my .htaccess file in public_html I have:
`php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com`

The file im loading from $.http:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Working";
} else {
    echo "Not finding username";
    exit;
}
```

Login Code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $query[0]['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $query[0]['image'];
$_SESSION['role'] = $query[0]['role'];
$_SESSION['banned'] = $query[0]['banned'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $query[0]['id'];
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['useragent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+604800,"/",".example.com");
header("Location: /"); exit;
```

EDIT:
api.example.com's doc directory is /api and not the conventional /public_html/api would this make a difference?

**Edit: Everything was solved once I moved the root/api docs folder to root/public_html/api and then used relative paths in the JS.**

Comment: You _do_ have `session_start()` at the top of the page you are calling via angular yes?

Comment: @Stuart Yes I do. It does: if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

Comment: Is it named? Maybe try:  `$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.some_domain.com');
session_start();`

Comment: @Stuart its named the default PHPSESSID - also the code you just put, should I have that in the login script or on the ajax script?

Comment: at the top of your php scripts. ideally the first two lines of that would be in some site-global config thats read by each and every ophp page...

Comment: @Stuart I just checked the cookie and even though `.example.com` is set via .htaccess, no initial . is on the cookie's domain section. (From F12)

Comment: You'll need that dot to designate the cookie across a subdomain

Comment: @Stuart I found out it was because setcookie (To make it expire in 7 days - which doesnt even work anyway) i added `,".example.com"` to the end of setcookie() and it is now .example.com in the domain, but its still not working.

Comment: **Just found out, manually going to the url works, is this possibly a cors issue? I for some reason had to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: header for it to be able to even load, is this possibly a cors issue?**

Comment: It's a problem with cookies. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: @Croises It works fine, just if I use a JS request to call the link, it will do a CORS error

Comment: >My subdomain: api.example.com (root/api) should be `api.example.com (root/public_html/api)`